# How should I install cups-pdf from source?

Tags: cups

On Ubuntu 12.10, I want to install cups-pdf. Using `apt-get install cups-pdf` works okay, but I want to install it in code source.

This is what I've tried:

1. Download code from http://www.physik.uni-wuerzburg.de/~vrbehr/cups-pdf/src/
2. Build cups-pdf:

   ```
   gcc -o cups-pdf `cups-config --cflags` cups-pdf.c `cups-config --libs`
   ```
3. Run the following:

   ```
   cp cups-pdf /usr/lib/cups/backend/
   cp ../extra/cups-pdf.conf /etc/cups
   cp ../extra/CUPS-PDF_opt.ppd  /usr/share/cups/model/CUPS-PDF_opt.ppd 
   lpadmin -p PDFprinter -E -v cups-pdf:/ -P /usr/share/cups/model/CUPS-PDF_opt.ppd 
   lpadmin -d PDFprinter
   ```
4. Try to print a file to PDF:

   ```
   lp Hello.c
   ```
5. **Nothing happened**

Comment: This is really off-topic for [so]. I'd suggest you ask n [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com) but I think you need to pin down the problem more closely first.

Comment: i just want to know about CUPS not ubuntu!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fond answer [How_to_install_CUPS-PDF_OpenSolarisx86.pdf](http://www.cups-pdf.de/contrib/How_to_install_CUPS-PDF_OpenSolarisx86.pdf).

The point is :

```
chmod 0700 /usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf
```